# How to populate datagridview based on SqlCommand or SqlDataAdapter on where clause? SqlDataAdapter doesn't work with where?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

```
// for delete it works, but for search no

// this is the delete part, afterwards I call the displaymethod to display the results after deletion
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtArtistDelete.Text != "")
    {
        command = new SqlCommand("delete from dbo.catalog where artist=@artist", connection);

        connection.Open();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@artist", txtArtistDelete.Text);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Record deleted successfully!");

        DisplayData();
        ClearData();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select an artist to delete");
    }
}

private void DisplayData()
{
    connection.Open();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adpter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from dbo.catalog", connection);
    adpter.Fill(dt);

    dgvCatalog.DataSource = dt;
    connection.Close();
}

// but after search I can not do that
private void btnCautare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    command = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.catalog where title = @title", connection);

    connection.Open();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", txtArtistDelete.Text);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adpter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from dbo.catalog where title = @title", connection);
    adpter.Fill(dt);

    dgvCatalog.DataSource = dt;

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}

// I get this error: 
// System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@title".'  
// I want to see in the datagridview only that searched record. 
// How can I do that with SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter?
```

How to populate datagridview based on `SqlCommand` or `SqlDataAdapter` with a where clause? `SqlDataAdapter` doesn't work with `where`

Comment: `dt.Fill(reader)`,? You can get the reader from `command.ExecuteReader()`. Don't forget to dispose all your SQL objects with `using` blocks

Comment: Note: there are **much** more efficient ways to use those DB provider objects and it is all well documented.  For a "search"  you can filter the existing results using the `RowFilter` property of the DGV datasource.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this more efficienty but let's proceed with the above code.
As the error says 'Must declare the scalar variable "@title".'

Replace your code with this

```
command = new SqlCommand("select *  from dbo.catalog where title=@title", connection);
connection.Open();
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", txtArtistDelete.Text);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adpter = new SqlDataAdapter(command); //Pass the SqlCommand object command as argument to SqlDataAdapter as it already contains the parameter @title in it
adpter.Fill(dt);
dgvCatalog.DataSource = dt;

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```